# Can't bind to 'countUp' since it isn't a known property of 'h1'. countup.js-angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I want to have a countup in one of my components... using **countup.js-angular2**

As in the gitup repo, i did everything i was suppose to do, it is still not working

```
import { CountUpModule } from 'countup.js-angular2';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        .....,
        CountUpModule
    ],
})

html 
<h1 [countUp]="endVal">0</h1>

typescript
endVal: number = 100;
```

**Error -**

> Can't bind to 'countUp' since it isn't a known property of 'h1'.

Comment: I think you miss some declarations. For example  add some directive  from `countUpModule` to `h1`

Comment: Directives like?

Comment: https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js-angular2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking [at the docs](https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js-angular2) they seem to be missing the fact that Ionic uses lazy loading and each page is also a module.

Add the module to your (pagename).module.ts file as well, using the same way as the app.module.ts.

Comment: If this solves your issue don't forget to update the question you asked on the github repo as well so you dont waste peoples time :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<h1 countUp [endVal]="endVal">0</h1>
```

countUp is a directive, it shouldn´t be in square brackets.

Regards

Comment: Can't bind to 'endVal' since it isn't a known property of 'h1'.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on versions, this issue https://github.com/inorganik/ngx-countUp/issues/43 says about versions conflict.

Uninstall `npm uninstall countup.js-angular2` old version and it will work.

Also with `countup.js-angular2@6.0.2` `[endVal]` would work.